# How to test CSS properties defined inside a class with react testing library

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, testing, react-testing-library

I am trying to test CSS properties that i have defined inside a class in css, wing the react testing library. However I am unable to do so.

Adding the simplified snippets.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import styled from "styled-components";

const Title = styled.span`
    display: none;
    background: red;
`

test("testRender", () => {

    render(
        <div>
            <Title>Test</Title>
        </div>
    )

    const spanElement = screen.getByText("Test");
    const elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(spanElement);
    expect(elementStyle.display).toBe('none');
});
```

The test fails at the expect statement. I have tried refactoring to traditional css, there also the test fails. In both cases, I have tested it manually and the styles are taking effect.

I also understand that we should not directly test CSS properties, but I have tried testing the visibility with toBeVisible(), but that only works if the `display: none` is directly entered as a style, and not as part of a class.

This should be a very simple thing, that works out of the box, but I have been at it for some time now, without any luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `expect(screen.getByText("Test")).not.toBeVisible();`

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import styled from "styled-components";

it("does display", () => {
  const Title = styled.span`
    display: block;
    background: red;
  `;

  render(
    <div>
      <Title>Test</Title>
    </div>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("Test")).toBeVisible();
});

it("doesn't display", () => {
  const Title = styled.span`
    display: none;
    background: red;
  `;

  render(
    <div>
      <Title>Test</Title>
    </div>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("Test")).not.toBeVisible();
});
```

...see the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-river-l6rn6?file=/App.test.js

Comment: Realised the sandbox test was failing. Have updated to fix issue.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @ourmaninamsterdam answer.

In addition, for checking appearance or disappearance of any element, you can also use `.not.toBeInTheDocument` like so:

```js
expect(screen.queryByText("Test")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

NOTE: You must use `queryByText` instead of `getByText` in this case since `queryByText` wont throw an error if it doesn't find the element (it will return null).

Official docs Reference - https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance#nottobeinthedocument